# How to increment by 1 in cloud firestore using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am trying to increase a particular field value using batch and i am able to increase normally but when i am using batch i am not able to control.here is my tried solution

```
await rootCollections.Campaigns.doc(campaign.campaignId).set(
          {
            history: {
              success: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
            },
          },
          { merge: true },
        );
```

and here is the condition for using batch which is not working properly

```
const batch =  db.batch();

const campaignRef = rootCollections.Campaigns.doc(campaign.campaignId);
        batch.set(
          campaignRef,
          {
            history: {
              failure: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
            },
          },
          { merge: true },
        );
await batch.commit()
```

Comment: You're not committing the batch yet: `batch.commit()`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i am doing that but still not able to do it

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
const batch =  db.batch();

const campaignRef = rootCollections.Campaigns.doc(campaign.campaignId);
        batch.update(
          campaignRef,
          {
            history: {
              failure: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
            },
          },
          { merge: true },
        );
await batch.commit()
```

Instead of using `set` use `update`, it will do the work.